# Is it possible to setup websocket server (android/ios) in local network/hotspot and connect via PWA?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, progressive-web-apps

**I'm planning to create a PWA as a medium to exchange real-time data between multiple devices (android,ios & etc) in offline local network**. Looking at the options, I'm considering to use nodejs(ws library) and run it in android(assume an android tablet will act as a local server via hotspot) as a host.

Is this the best way to achieve the goal and also sustainable for numbers of customer(assume up to 50 devices connected to that 1 android host)?

*Just assume it is a local ordering system between shop owner and customers that just connect to the hotspot that was created locally to join the network. Actually it also will have the ability to sync data with online db which not the main question here.*

Answer (score 0):

sure any website can use web sockets.

However, service workers only capture HTTPS traffic, so none of the websocket traffic passes through the service worker.

For what you are building I would see a combination of websockets and HTTPS traffic. The websockets would be used to update a client when state on the server changes.

For example, a customer places an order. The back office needs to know a new order is expected so they can full fill it. The back office interface would be notified through the web socket channel.

Comment: so online server with ssl is necessary to use websocket?
back to my situation where i would like to run it locally.
Any other option i can look into?

Comment: you should always use TLS for connections, so secure web socket :)
As far as running from an Android tablet or phone I could not tell you about that. I mean you could run from a Windows or Raspberry Pi for sure. And I am pretty sure there is a way to setup a local server on an Android device.